# First use of ‘template’ in molecular biology

Tags: etymology

In modern English the term ‘template’ usually refers to a pattern, mould or former used as a guide to create objects of a similar shape. In molecular biology it is used for a DNA strand which is ‘copied’, but where the object produced is not a true copy of the ‘template’ but what is called a (reverse) complement of it, using the A↔︎T G↔︎C rules which preserve the integrity of the information:

```
  ATGGCCT →  : Template DNA
← TACCGGA    : DNA ‘copy’
```

This is a little like a printing block where one has ‘ɔ’, the mirror image of e.g. a letter ‘c’ to print that letter.

My question is whether anyone knows of the first or early usage of the term ‘template’ in either this molecular biological context or in a similar context where the object produced differs from the ‘template’.

(I obviously don’t expect people on this list to be familiar with molecular biology, but wonder if there are resources for this kind of search.)

Comment: [**template**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/template) definition 1: 
*a pattern, **mould**, or the like.* Definition 6: *Genetics. a strand of DNA or RNA that **serves as a pattern** for the synthesis of a **complementary** strand of nucleic acid or protein.* As you can see, the "genetics" sense is a simple extension from the "base" sense of ***mould*** (which is axiomatically an ***inverse*** image of whatever will be cast from it).

Comment: I would guess that the folks standing around when DNA was being discovered used the term, as it is a natural one to use.  And no doubt the term was used in other contexts within biology earlier than that.  It's kind of like asking for the first use of the word "cell" in biology.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OK, I should have thought about ‘mould’. I suppose it wasn’t such a change of usage as I had thought.

Comment: @HotLicks Not really, and not very helpful. DNA was discovered in the 19th century, but its double-stranded nature not until 1953. It is of interest when the template concept arose and how it was employed, and I was really wondering whether the language analysis experts on this list had tools or access to databases that could answer this sort of question.

Comment: Well, Ngram finds some uses of "DNA template" in [1961](https://books.google.com/books?id=euxFAQAAIAAJ&q=%22dna+template%22&dq=%22dna+template%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikvZLMv6rNAhUNLlIKHYSWCmM4ChDoAQg4MAY).  But my understanding is that the template nature of DNA was understood to a degree even before the structure was deciphered.

Comment: @HotLicks That's interesting. How does the Ngram thing operate?

Comment: Looking at the first few results for template in the 19th century in Google Books, we [find](https://books.google.com/books?id=NiRHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA352&dq=template&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpjNjS4arNAhVDaD4KHfqGDHIQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=template&f=false) the sentence "Consequently, we make from the male template A, Fig. 5, a female template K". This was written in 1883, and *template* in the engineering sense seems very rare before 1850 or so.

Comment: I think the modern usage originates from gene splicing and designer genes. It's usage has exploded with the development of CRISPR/Cas9 and engineered gene drive. Check the early research into the gene drive processes that occur in nature and led to the engineered gene drive processes.

Comment: To use Ngram, [go there](https://books.google.com/ngrams), type in a phrase, and press "Search".  After that it's an Adventure game.

Comment: @PhilSweet Thanks, but you must be a young man ;-). Gene splicing  post-dated the use of template in relation to DNA replication by over 10 years. It was discovered in 1973, whereas the quote from Hot Licks shows it was in use in 1961.

Comment: @PeterShor — I realized I have a compact edition of the complete OED (1928) and checked template there. It lists it under ‘templet’, defines it (in this sense) as “an instrument used as a gauge or guide to bring any piece of work to the desired shape…”, and its earliest example of usage is in 1819. There is a later more specialized definition in naval engineering (1874). Earlier usage (1677) is in building, but there it merely describes a timber, from which the word is thought to derive. So its use in the modern sense both literal and figurative is relatively recent.

Comment: I have now found a key paper where the term was used in 1953, with the implication that it was already current (although probably only in the preceding post-war years). I'm not sure whether to answer my own question giving the details, delete it, or modify it asking for examples of the development of the concept from the late 19th century. Advice would be welcomed.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, "contemplate", with the word split across lines, was very common back in the 1800s, to obscure things.

Comment: Ngram finds a use of [a template](https://books.google.com/books?id=RmU_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA17&dq=%22a+template%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4ssCFv6vNAhUJKFIKHem1Avo4FBDoAQhHMAg#v=onepage&q=%22a%20template%22&f=false) in 1834 and [the template](https://books.google.com/books?id=UXEOAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA14&dq=%22the+template%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj09oC_v6vNAhUBUVIKHX2fCA84HhDoAQgsMAM#v=onepage&q=%22the%20template%22&f=false) in 1839.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the OED (online, but page from OED2, 1989), it was first used in 1949:

> If we accept the view that the normal cellular proteins are formed as negative replicas of a positive cellular template, we are confronted with a serious dilemma.
>   <sub>[The Quarterly Review of Biology](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2809736.pdf?casa_token=GQsKLmwxIH8AAAAA:raltIwxAY-wLx7hT28cDDAUljAsDnB4XUONUkarwgBGjCLKry828jxO7aWfFHYmOfAxWxXOyAPCHzEurboNL-h8P3N2QXzh-jauKYVniWVHx3WFcTN9O)</sub>

It also has a bracketed quote from 1904, which means it's not really an example of the sense, but it's relevant to its development:

> The protoplasmic complex may be regarded as built up of a series of associated templates which serve as patterns to determine change in the various directions necessary for the maintenance of vital processes and of growth.
>   <sub>[Proceedings of the Royal Society of London](https://books.google.com/books?id=_DRGAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA702&lpg=PA702&dq="The+protoplasmic+complex+may+be+regarded+as+built+up+of+a+series".)</sub>

Comment: I am accepting this answer on the assumption that the OED is correct. Even if it is not, it is an pertinent example that predates the elucidation of the structure of DNA and the idea of nucleic acid templates. It is also biologically interesting in relation to early views of the origin of antibody specificity (now known to be incorrect). Well done.